# Cascade Deleting Many-To-Many relationship in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, cascading-deletes

I have three tables in my database:

```
Articles: ArticleID (PK) 
Tags: TagiID (PK)
ArticleTagMapping: ArticleID(FK,PK), TagID(FK,PK)
```

ArticleTagMapping has a composite primary key. This resulted in a many-to-many relationship in my entity model as expected. I have set both the foreign key relationships to cascade on delete in database.

I am trying to delete Article via C# code. This errors out...

```
var ArticleToDelete = context.Articles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ArticleID == ArticleID);
context.Articles.DeleteObject(ArticleToDelete);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I want to delete all the ArticleTagMapping entries for that article without affecting the Tags entries.
I DO NOT want to Delete any entries from Tags table, but only entries from the mapping table. Need help here...

Comment: If it "errors out" (blue screen?) it *could* be a hardware failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not shown us the error. But I suspect you're having problems with relationships that prevent deleting the entity.

in SQL Server Management studio, right click on `ArticleTagMapping` table-> `Design`->Right click->`Relationships...`
Now select the relationship between `Articles` table and `ArticleTagMapping` table. Expand `INSERT And UPDATE Specification` and change both Rules to `Cascade`. By doing so, whenever you delete an article, all the related relationships in `ArticleTagMapping` table will be deleted automatically:

```
var article = context.Articles.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == articleID);
context.DeleteObject(article);
```

Comment: Apologies for a little delay here. Thanks kamyar, for spending time and reviewing this. Actually my entity model file edmx was not updated and there was an SQL Server version (2005/2008) mismatch causing an error here. But for keeping this thread clean, I will mark your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the answers concerning EF6:

If the foreign keys are set, **referential integrity** should do automatically via the DBMS itself when deleting the parent entities.

If you use code first, as far as I learned in a MVA tutorial, **ON DELETE CASCADE** is the default behavior set by EF6. If running DB first, you should alter your childtable(s)...

Here is the link: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/implementing-entity-framework-with-mvc-8931?l=pjxcgEC3_7104984382
In the **Video** it's mentioned at **20:00** upwards and in the **slide presentation** it is said on **page 14**.

Cheers