# Many to Many Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my model I've got a 1.* to 0.* relationship, so a many-to-many with a minimum of 1 on one side. For instance, Reader has multiple Books (0 or more), and Book has multiple Readers (at least 1). Is it possible to configure Entity Framework to do a cascade delete of the Book if the last Reader is deleted?

Comment: "If the foreign keys are set, referential integrity should do automatically via the DBMS itself when deleting the parent entities." -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340354/cascade-deleting-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 4):

You can try as shown below by using `Fluent API`.

```
      mapping.Entity<Reader>()   
       .HasMany(x => x.Books)
       .WithRequired() 
       .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Please read [**Enabling Cascade Delete**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete) article too.